# Call to AsyncFacebookRunner request() gives error

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to get photos information of a friend's public album. If I use:

```
AsyncFacebookRunnerObj.request(currentAlbumID +"/photos", new myRequestListner, refString);
```

I get all the information of the photos but I want only following fields id, name, source, and created_time, but when I modify my query as

```
AsyncFacebookRunnerObj.request(currentAlbumID +"/photos?fields=id,name,source,created_time&", new myRequestListner, refString);
```

it gives me following error:

```
Unknown fields: created_time?access_token=206284639416574|bb1b1eb05fb1dcde78cb98ff.3-100002550378811|GLcB2DC3Tyc5VMWukaB9nPW6QF0
```

In first case this token also gets appended but no error is thrown but in second case Facebook-sdk gives error.

I will appreciate any help!

Thanks.

Comment: I made the same query on Facebook in a browser it worked but if I put ....&? it returns me empty JSONObject. So the problem is really the ? mark that gets appended in front of the access_token. the request function is appending it automatically. Does anyone knows how to remove this ? symbol from query?

Comment: Yes, you'll have to edit the request method and change it so it doesn't - like I stated below.

Comment: @Berdon. Thanks. I got it. I changed the openUrl in Utils. It has the complete string url. Since when you request fields you use '=' otherwise there is no '=' sign so I searched for it and then changed the ? symbol to at line no 146.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the AsyncFacebookRunnerObj of your own creation or not? If it is, you need to alter the way the access token is appended to check for preceding GET parameters and if present use a "&" rather than a "?". If it isn't, you'll have to modify the source to do so anyway...

Comment: Thanks for response. Actually its an Object of the the default AsyncFacebookRunner class of Facebook SDK. I am not an experienced developer, can you please tell me how and where can I make this change because ? mark is appended to the token in each case and if we look at Facebook Graph APIs Page, if we call ..../me/friends or any Graph API object like friend, photo, album etc ? is appended to the query followed by token but if we add ..?fields=... then only & is appended followed by token. In my case ? is appended no matter what. If I modify this will it affect other queries?

Comment: Are you refering to following request method of Facebook.java        [`code`](public String request(String graphPath, Bundle params, String httpMethod)
            throws FileNotFoundException, MalformedURLException, IOException {
        params.putString("format", "json");
        if (isSessionValid()) {
            params.putString(TOKEN, getAccessToken());
        }
        String url = (graphPath != null) ? GRAPH_BASE_URL + graphPath
                                         : RESTSERVER_URL;
        return Util.openUrl(url, httpMethod, params);
    })